# Prepared Statements: Method 'prepare' not found in class

Tags: php

I am just beginning to learn prepared statements, but for some reason I copied and pasted this code from another project of mine (which works) and it is telling me that the mysqli object has no prepared statement methods. What have I forgotten in this code snippet? Later portions that are irrelevant to the issue have been redacted, but for each object I try to call on $stmt, it says the method is not found.

```
$dbhost = 'redacted';
$dbname = 'redacted';
$dbuser = 'redacted';
$dbpass = 'redacted';

$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass, $dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($db));
```

Later this is called:

```
function register($db) {
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
}


switch ($action) {
case 'register':
    register($db);
    break;
case 'login':
    login($db);
    break;
}
```

Comment: You need add `global $db` so `$db` will be visible in your function.

Comment: @barell it's a passed argument here

Comment: I passed it in from another function, however, should I don't think it should be necessary, unless there's some feature of PHP I am unaware of. Which is totally possible!

Comment: You are right, didn't notice. How do you invoke your function?

Comment: I have edited the original post to show. $action is a POST variable that is defined above all this.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure you don't overwrite `$db` variable somewhere?

Comment: I'm so confused. I changed $db->prepare to mysqli_prepare and it works. Even though I copied and pasted the original code from another working project...

Comment: `var_dump($db)` inside your method and see just what it is.